# Sharepoint - Workflow History - Schedule export weekly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, export, workflow-history

I am looking for some assistance on how to setup a scheduled task which will weekly export my workflow history to a file location. I am able to export to excel - I now need to automate the process. Perhaps a PS solution?

https://mysite/Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use below to export your items to CSV file from Workflow History List. You might need to tweak code as per your needs.

```
$listTitle = "Workflow History"
$csvFilePath = "C:\Temp\items.csv"
$sSiteColUrl = ""  
$sUserName = ""  
$sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString 
$accountName = ""

try 
{   
    #Adding the Client OM Assemblies         
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

    #SPO Client Object Model Context 
    $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteColUrl)  
    $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUsername, $sPassword)   
    $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list = $spoCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)

    #Use CamlQuery if you want to filter   
    #$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    #$query.ViewXml = ""
    #[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection]$items = $list.GetItems($query)

    #Get all items
    $listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
    $spoCtx.Load($listItems)
    $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

    $itemCollection = @()

    $listItems |  foreach {
    $exportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $exportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["WorkflowInstance"]
    $exportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Department" -value $_["WorkflowAssociation"]
    $exportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User" -value $_["User"].LookupValue
    $exportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Desc" -value $_["Description"]
    $itemCollection += $exportItem
 }
    $itemCollection | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

    $spoCtx.Dispose() 
} 
catch [System.Exception] 
{ 
    write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString()    
}
```

Save file in ps1 format and create a task scheduler to run weekly.